# SceneKit – Mapping physical 360 rotation

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, quaternions, core-motion, euler-angles

I am having a hard time mapping device motion (sensor fusion) to SceneKit node rotation. The premise of the problem is as follows,

I have sphere, and the camera is positioned to be inside the the sphere such that the geometric center of sphere and camera node's center coincide. What i want to achieve is when i rotate physically around a point, the motion needs to be mapped accurately on the camera as well.

The implementaion details are as follows:

I have a node, with a sphere as geomertry and is a child to root node. I am using sensor fusion to get attitude quternions and then 
converting them to euler angles. The code for that is:

```
- (SCNVector3)eulerAnglesFromCMQuaternion:(CMQuaternion) {
    GLKQuaternion gq1 =  GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90), 1, 0, 0);
    GLKQuaternion gq2 =  GLKQuaternionMake(q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w);
    GLKQuaternion qp  =  GLKQuaternionMultiply(gq1, gq2);
    CMQuaternion rq =   {.x = qp.x, .y = qp.y, .z = qp.z, .w = qp.w};
    CGFloat roll = atan2(-rq.x*rq.z - rq.w*rq.y, .5 - rq.y*rq.y - rq.z*rq.z);
    CGFloat pitch = asin(-2*(rq.y*rq.z + rq.w*rq.x));
    CGFloat yaw = atan2(rq.x*rq.y - rq.w*rq.z, .5 - rq.x*rq.x - rq.z*rq.z);
    return SCNVector3Make(roll, pitch, yaw);
}
```

The conversion equation is from  [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=wCfWkc_E3GkC&lpg=PP1&dq=fletcher%20dunn%203d%20math%20primer&hl=de&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=false). I have used to book as a reference, haven't read it. But definitely on my reading list.

Now to simulate the physical rotation in SceneKit, am rotating my node containing SCNCamera. This is a child to rootNode. And am using .rotation
property to do the same. One thing to note here is that
Now my device motion update thread looks something like this

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical toQueue:mq withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CMAttitude *currentAttitude = motion.attitude;
    [SCNTransaction begin];
    [SCNTransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    SCNVector3 v = [self eulerAnglesFromCMQuaternion:currentAttitude.quaternion];
    self.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make( v.y, -v.x, 0); //SCNVector3Make(roll, yaw, pitch)
    [SCNTransaction commit];
}];
```

Something of caution here is the euler angles are different for device and for SceneKit node. The links explain them.

[SceneKit Euler Angles](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/eulerAngles)

[CMAttitude Euler Angles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMAttitude)

And in  my understanding the mapping between two goes something like this.

[image: [Image]]

Now the problem I am facing is, the camera's 360 degree rotation is over before my physical rotation about a point is.
Which am trying to dpecit via the following image.

[image: [Image2]]

I doubt the quaternion -> euler angle conversion is causing the error, and quaternion math is way over my head as of now.

I hope i have provided all the information, if anything more is required am only glad to add.

Comment: This answer solves for all device orientations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823012/cameranode-rotate-as-ios-device-moving

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for your description of your problem and the beginning of a solution!
I am quite sure that this can not be done with the Euler angles, because of the [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) (loose of 1 degree of freedom).

The solution that worked for is to get the attitude and use the quaternion to set the orientation of the camera:

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical toQueue:myQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    CMAttitude *currentAttitude = motion.attitude;
    [SCNTransaction begin];
    [SCNTransaction setDisableActions:YES];

    SCNQuaternion quaternion = [self orientationFromCMQuaternion:currentAttitude.quaternion];
    _cameraNode.orientation = quaternion;

    [SCNTransaction commit];
}];
- (SCNQuaternion)orientationFromCMQuaternion:(CMQuaternion)q
{
    GLKQuaternion gq1 =  GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90), 1, 0, 0); // add a rotation of the pitch 90 degrees
    GLKQuaternion gq2 =  GLKQuaternionMake(q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w); // the current orientation
    GLKQuaternion qp  =  GLKQuaternionMultiply(gq1, gq2); // get the "new" orientation
    CMQuaternion rq =   {.x = qp.x, .y = qp.y, .z = qp.z, .w = qp.w}; 

    return SCNVector4Make(rq.x, rq.y, rq.z, rq.w);
}
```

Comment: It would be great to see how to adjust the code to a landscape orientation.

Comment: This answer solves for all device orientations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823012/cameranode-rotate-as-ios-device-moving

Answer (score 3):

If CoreMotion and SceneKit don't use the same convention for euler angles then you can probably use intermediate nodes to simplify the conversion. For example by having a hierarchy like:

```
YawNode
  |
  |___PitchNode
      |
      |___RollNode
          |
          |___CameraNode
```

YawNode, PitchNode, RollNode would rotate only around one single axis. 
Then by playing on the hierarchy order you can reproduce CoreMotion's convention.

That being said, I'm not sure the conversion quaternion -> euler is a great idea. I suspect that you won't get a continuous/smooth transition at angles like 0 / PI / 2PI...
I would try quaternion->matrix4 instead and update the "transform" of your node.

Comment: If i do a quaternion to rotation matrix (it'll be a 3x3 matrix or so the book says) how do i make it a 4x4 (padding?). Or how do i do a quaternion -> matrix4 conversion?

Comment: What about passing the CM quaternion into SceneKit as a quaternion? You can do that with the `SCNNode.orientation` property. (And if the coordinate spaces don't match, use an enclosing node or `pivot` to transform the space containing the node.)

Comment: @rickster: tried that, but still the difference between start and end exist. I had a check at the sensor value, looks like there is a drift of around 20 degrees. Sensors are fine since other apps works perfectly fine. What could possibly be wrong ?

Comment: To add to this, surprisingly the difference happens only when i move /rotate rightwards. And the rotation is perfect when i move leftwards.

Comment: @Toyos it'd be great to augment this answer with code snippets. Esp because this is a solution that works. Otherwise it's tough to translate the diagram.