# SceneKit: Camera movement based on CoreMotion

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, core-motion, scncamera

I'm attempting to emulate ARKit but using the device's front camera instead of the back one (and not restricted to iPhone X). So far I've managed to set up a simple scene with just a 3D model loaded in front of a SCNCamera and thanks to the snippet provided by Travis in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823012/cameranode-rotate-as-ios-device-moving/33695442#33695442) managed to orientate the SCNCamera according to the attitude of the device.

However, I still need translate the camera based on the device's movement so that I can visualize the object from different angles and "zoom" to it; and I can't figure out which data should I use. Is it the `userAcceleration` from the `CMDeviceMotion` object? I've noticed by logging that even if I keep the device relatively quiet I get some non-zero values for the components of the acceleration. Any hint or lead on how to approach this is truly appreciated.

Here's the basic code I've got so far:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!
    private let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    private var ringNode: SCNNode!
    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        setupMotionManager()
    }

    private func setupScene() {
        let objScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ring.obj")!
        ringNode = objScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ring", recursively: true)
        ringNode.applyUniformScale(0.003)
        ringNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ringNode)

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)          
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    private func setupMotionManager() {
        if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue(), withHandler: { (motion, error) in
                if let motion = motion {
                    self.cameraNode.orientation = motion.gaze(atOrientation: .portrait)
                    let acc = motion.userAcceleration
                    print("Acc: \(accDescription(acc))")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't. I ended up doing some rotation and translation of the nodes instead of the camera but without satisfying results.